# When should I use the bindgen crate instead of libloading?

Tags: rust

I want to consume a shared / dynamic library; what would be the best option?

Is there a loss of runtime speed by using libloading?

Comment: bindgen and libloading doesn't do the same job, you can use both for the same library for exemple.

Comment: is the only difference that bindgen generates the ffi bindings? What if I do not use bindings?

Comment: No they are completely different, there have nothing in commun, one load dynamic symbol into your program the other create binding for call function.